# Adding more than one button to a Ext.form.Formpanel in Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, handler, formpanel

I have the following code in javascript:

```
buttons: [{
                text: 'Yes',
                handler: function()
                        {
                        answer = 'true';
                        w.close();
                        }
            },{
                text: 'No',
                Handler: function()
                        {
                        answer = 'false';
                        w.close();
            }

        }]
```

But only the button labelled 'yes' responds. Any Ideas?

James

Comment: watch your casing. The `Handler` should be `handler`.

Comment: Ah thankyou! Been going around in circles and completely missed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misspelt 'handler' as 'Handler'. Silly syntax error!